# Controling a TextView not from it's Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a xml with a `TextView` called "tv", and I have an activity class of that xml that uses another class called "helper". i want that from helper i would be able to control what's written in the `TextView` "tv".

i dont want to use sharedprefernece because then the data will saty the same even if i turn off the app.

Comment: If you declare your TextView as protected static, then (after retrieving it in your MainActivity's onCreate), in your second ("helper") Activity you can use it like: `String myString = MainActivity.tv.getText();` and `MainActivity.tv.setText("Some text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an activity attribut to Helper class so you can handle everything from there.

```
Helper helper = new Helper();
helper.setMyActivity(this);
```

Then in helper class

```
TextView tv = (TextView) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.set("The title");
```